# Count previous occurrences in Pandas

Tags: pandas

How to count the past occurrences on every occurrence using pandas?

Given:

```
   A
0  x
1  y
2  z
3  x
4  x
5  y
```

Output:

```
   A  B
0  x  1
1  y  1
2  z  1
3  x  2
4  x  3
5  y  2
```

Comment: `df['B']=df.groupby('A').cumcount()+1`

Comment: @anky_91 thank you, and sorry for the duplicate